# derive the least squares estimate b1 from the normal equations

Tags: least-squares

I am stuck on the following question*:

derive the least squares estimate:

$$  b1 = \frac{\sum X_iY_i - \frac{\sum X_i \sum Y_i}{n}}
          {\sum X_i^2 - \frac{( \sum X_i)^2}{n}} $$

from the normal equations:

$$ (i)   \sum Y_i = nb_0 +  b_1 \sum X_i    $$
$$ (ii) \sum X_iY_i = b_0 \sum X_i + b_1 \sum X_i^2$$

I get:

$$ b1 = \frac { \sum X_i Y_i -  \frac {\sum X_i \sum Y_i}{n} }                      
              {(\sum X_i)^2 - \frac {(\sum X_i)^2}{n}} $$

I think I am there except that I have $(\sum X_i)^2$ instead of $\sum X_i^2$ in the demonimator. I take the latter to mean the sum (X * X) rather than the sum(X) * sum(X). However I cannot see how you would get sum (X * X)  from the original equations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Unless (X * X) is interpreted the matrix muliplication (X * X') where X is a column vector in which case $( \sum X_i)^2$ and $\sum X_i^2$ are equal.

(Please see below for working)

I first solve for $b_0$ with $i - (\frac {ii} {\sum X_i})$:

$(\frac {ii} {\sum X_i})$:    $  \frac{\sum X_iY_i}{\sum X_i} = b_0  + b_1 \sum X_i$

$(i - \frac {ii} {\sum X_i})$:   $  \sum Y_i -  \frac{\sum X_iY_i}{\sum X_i} = nb_0 - b_0$

rearranging yeilds:

$$  b_o = \frac {\sum X_i \sum Y_i - \sum X_i Y_i}{\sum X_i (n -1)} $$

then substituting into (i) (rearranged to isolate b1) and cancelling:

$$ b1 = \frac { \sum Y_i - n \frac { \sum X_i \sum Y_i - \sum X_i Y_i} {\sum X_i(n-1)}} { \sum X_i} $$

$$ b1 \sum X_i = \frac { \sum X_i \sum Y_i (n-1) - n \sum X_i \sum Y_i - n\sum X_i Y_i}                      {\sum X_i(n-1)} $$

$$ b1 = \frac {(n \sum X_i \sum Y_i  - \sum X_i \sum Y_i)  - (n \sum X_i \sum Y_i - n\sum X_i Y_i)}                      {\sum X_i \sum X_i(n-1)} $$

$$ b1 = \frac {n \sum X_i Y_i -  \sum X_i \sum Y_i }                      
              {\sum X_i \sum X_i(n-1)} $$

$$ b1 = \frac {n \sum X_i Y_i -  \sum X_i \sum Y_i }                      
              {n(\sum X_i)^2 - (\sum X_i)^2} $$

multiply both sides by $\frac {\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$

$$ b1 = \frac { \sum X_i Y_i -  \frac {\sum X_i \sum Y_i}{n} }                      
              {(\sum X_i)^2 - \frac {(\sum X_i)^2}{n}} $$

*q2.30 from Applied Linear Statistical Models, Neter et al 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs when you divide $(ii)$ by $\sum X_i$. The result should be:
$$\frac{\sum X_iY_i}{\sum X_i} = b_0  + b_1 \frac{\sum X_i^2}{\sum X_i}
$$ because, as you mentioned, $\sum X_i^2$ does not mean $(\sum X_i)(\sum X_i)$.